# How Do I Conditionally Filter a store?

Tags: extjs

I am fairly new to ExtJS and I am having trouble with my stores.  I have two combo boxes on a pop up and each is set to a store.

```
items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox', itemId: 'facility', name: 'facilityId', fieldLabel: 'Facility', displayField: 'name', valueField: 'id', queryMode: 'local', allowOnlyWhitespace: false, forceSelection: true,
                    store: {
                        model: 'Common.model.Facility', autoDestroy: true, sorters: 'name'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, newValue) { this.up('window').filterLocations(); }
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox', fieldLabel: 'Location', name: 'locationId', displayField: 'name', valueField: 'id', queryMode: 'local', allowOnlyWhitespace: false, forceSelection: true,
                    store: {
                        model: 'Common.model.PrimaryLocation', autoDestroy: true, sorters: 'name'
                    },
                    // Strange hack from Sencha to get around filter-on-load issue http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?80079-Problem-to-filter-a-combobox-s-store-at-store-s-load-event
                    triggerAction: 'all', lastQuery: ''
                }
            ],
```

It is referenced here(I think) in another code file(I'll only post the one I care about for now):

```
// Load comboboxes

        window.getFacilityId().getStore().load({
            scope: this,
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                if (!success) {
                    Ext.log({ level: 'error', msg: 'Error loading facility list', dump: operation });
                    var text = (operation.getError() ? operation.getError().response.responseText : operation.getResponse().responseText);
                    var msg = Ext.decode(text).message;
                    Ext.Msg.show({ title: 'Error', msg: 'Error loading facility data.<br>' + msg, buttons: Ext.Msg.OK, icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR });
                }
                else {

                    // Select first entry if only one

                    if (records.length == 1)
                        window.getFacilityId().setValue(records[0].get('id'));
                }
            }
        });
```

There is a field on the form that calls this has a value I need to do a comparison on.  If the value is null or 0, then I really don't need to do anything because as it is, it displays all the facilities in the database.
However, if it is not null or 0, then I need the store to be filtered to only show the single facility in the list that matches the one on the value that I am comparing it to.

How do I make this filter work?  To make it easy, just assume that the facility store has just id and name as fields and assume that the value I'm comparing it to is facilityId.

Something like:

```
if (facilityId == null)
  // What?

Thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using `load` method on the store, set filter if your condition is met like:

```
window.getFacilityId().getStore().setFilters({
  property: 'id',
  operator: '=',
  value: facilityId
});
```

Comment: So, that seemed to work to filter the items in my combo box, but when I tried to set my combo to the filtered record(display) it wouldn't.  In my callback function(records, operation, success), I check if records.length == 1 to do a setValue to the [0] record, but all the records are in records, not just the filtered one(s).  Is there a way I can tell which records in that collection are chosen(not filtered) so I can set that one?  The filter I set should either return 4 records or 1 depending on the filter check.  If it returns 1 I want it to be displayed, otherwise, none selected is fine.

Comment: @brianpleshek Is your store filtered locally or remotely?

Comment: To be honest, it's hard for me to tell.  Enterprise framework is doing its thing.  However, I believe that it is locally.  I'm getting 4 records which is all there are in this particular table.  The code you gave me is bound to the combobox.  I was hoping there was a collection property showing which of the 4 records(or all of them) are passing(or being excluded by) the filter.

Comment: If store is filtered locally, you will get unfiltered data from server using `load`, and filtering is done on the client side by ExtJS JavaScript code, basically filtering out records from an array that don't satisfy your criteria. That's why you get all 4 records in the callback. Is it not possible to use the same criteria that you use to decide whether to apply the filter or not, instead of checking `records.length`?